# In Illustrator CS6, how to I paste to another file while preserving all the layers

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

I have one master file containing 3 figures, each possessing multiple layers. I'd like to separate each figure to its own .ai file, so I tried copy-pasting each figure to a new .ai file. However, the pasted figure is all in one layer. I've been searching for an analog to 'Paste Remember Layers' in CS6, but haven't been successful.

Does know which paste option preserves layer, or perhaps a quick way to do this?

I could simply delete two figures and save as a new file- there's a bunch of other stuff on there and it would be kind of a hassle, but it's a suitable last resort.

Answer (score 3):

Layers Panel Menu > Make certain `Paste Remembers Layers` is **checked**.

Do this **before** you copy. Then copy/paste to another AI file.

It's right there on the Layers Panel in CS6....

[image]

Note that in some cases it can be **exceptionally helpful** to ensure the layers you are copying have **unique names** rather than `Layer 1`, `Layer 2`, etc. Becuase when you paste.... layers will *merge* if the new file has a layer of the same name of the copied layer.

If this isn't working for you, I'm afraid you'll need to explain the problem you are having further.